# F# 2D Array alternate creation

Tags: arrays, f#, creation

I am using the Array2D module in f# and want to create a sudoku game board (a 9x9 array) using it. Right now I have something that works and that looks like this:

```
let createInitialArray = [| [|for x in 1 .. 9 -> createSquare x 1 |]; 
                            [|for x in 1 .. 9 -> createSquare x 2 |]; 
                            [|for x in 1 .. 9 -> createSquare x 3 |]; 
                            [|for x in 1 .. 9 -> createSquare x 4 |]; 
                            [|for x in 1 .. 9 -> createSquare x 5 |]; 
                            [|for x in 1 .. 9 -> createSquare x 6 |]; 
                            [|for x in 1 .. 9 -> createSquare x 7 |]; 
                            [|for x in 1 .. 9 -> createSquare x 8 |]; 
                            [|for x in 1 .. 9 -> createSquare x 9 |] |]

let sudokuGame = Array2D.init 9 9 ( fun i j -> createInitialArray.[j].[i] )
```

My question is if there is a better or more compact way to write this?

In [MSDN about arrays in general](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233214.aspx) and [MSDN about Array2D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353794.aspx) I've  learned that there are a few other functions, for example init, initBased, create and createBased. As I'm still only a few weeks into learning the language I don't see how I can work with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can totally do away with `createInitialArray` and inline the call to `createSquare`:

```
let sudokuGame = Array2D.init 9 9 ( fun i j -> createSquare i j )
```

Or even shorter, dropping the tautological lambda:

```
let sudokuGame = Array2D.init 9 9 createSquare
```

Comment: Ah it looks really good! I'm on the bus home now but will try it out soon. Thanks!